# Flexible customization - Generating word document using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, ms-word, t4, templating

Problem - Generate a word document from information retrieved from database.

My solution - Create a word document template add fields/tags in places where values need to be inserted. The template will require tables and charts as well. Using document reflector that comes with open office xml sdk reflect on the document template and extract the w:document section and port it to C#. The rest of the logic revolves simply around finding the fields/tags, replacing them, etc. Very simple approach but not very flexible!

Challenge - I want the user to have the ability to customize the template or the generated document output. But this will not be possible if I embed the template logic in code.

Any other possibilities - I looked around at Templating using T4 and RazorEngine but could not find any concrete examples of how to create word documents using these two technologies.

Now what is the best approach?
I would really appreciate your inputs on what is the best and most flexible way to generate word documents using C#.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working a project where the business users are designing word template with mail merge fields and we are populating the values using a 3rd party software package Aspose Words. http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

The software includes a library for merging data from datatables into the mail merge fields in the word document.

I also wrote a customized word task pane add in that retrieves data views from the database and lists the fields in a drag/drop interface that mimics a crystal or sql report writing interface.

Probably would of been easier to just use crystal or sql reporting though...

Comment: Thanks Robert, But I am keen on a free api or library.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to generate the contents of an Office doc using T4 or Razor and then package it up.  The TestScribe powertool for Visual Studio Test Manager does just that with T4. There is a thread by Sally Cavanagh in the Q&A on this page http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e79e4a0f-f670-47c2-9b8a-3b6f664bf4ae that  suggests a way to look at the T4 templates that it uses, which might get you jump-started.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i am after. Have a look at this post, http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/01/07/build-manager-extensionndashscribe-for-build-notes.aspx. I however, want to have the generation flexible enough for the user to be able to edit it themselves.

Comment: The only problem i see with T4 is the lack of a good free editor. I have come down to doing this with razor, unless you can help change my opinion about T4.

Comment: I don't have an agenda to change your mind.  If Razor works for you, then go with Razor.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atverma/archive/2011/12/31/utility-to-generate-word-documents-from-templates-using-visual-studio-2010-and-open-xml-2-0-sdk.aspx) is sample to play word document template with C#

Comment: Thanks, great sample. However, I would appreciate if you could point me to something where I can see samples for "1. Building tables i.e. looping through the object to generate a table" "2. Build charts, graphs".

Comment: Firoz, this is perfect! Thanks once again for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a content control databinding approach.

[XML Mapping Task Pane for Word 2007/2010](http://xmlmapping.codeplex.com/) is an authoring tool.

To create an instance document, you just attach your XML data file.

If the resulting documents will be opened in Word, that is all that is required: Word will bind the data itself.  If your consuming application is not Word, you might want to resolve the bindings yourself (eg via Open XML SDK).

Content control databinding isn't intended to support repeats and conditionals.  For a way to do that, look at my [OpenDoPE convention](http://www.opendope.org)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Templater](http://templater.info/). Disclamer: I'm the author.

Comment: I really like the approach, however, i am myself writing an open source tool, your offering is paid, though definitely worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com/).  They are Java based but some of the templating features and output options might be ideal.  You can call the command line interfaces unless they also have something better to reach from C#.